# How to add styling to divs which have inputs with some css class onsubmit?

Tags: jquery

I can't get what I'm doing wrong.

I want to add background to parent div if input is invalid.

I mean - add background to field2 if email input hasClass error.

Here is my js code:

```
 $('.login').submit(function() {

 $(':input').each(function() {

 if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {

 $(".field2").has($(this)).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
  }
 if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {

 $(".field2").has($(this)).removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');

  }
 })

});
```

I have working code:

```
 $('input').each(function() {

  if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {

 $(".field2").has(this).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
  }
 if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {

 $(".field2").has(this).removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');

 }
 })
}
window.setInterval(foo3, 1);
```

**but why previous variant isn't working ?**

and HTML:

```
   <div class="field2">
  <label for="user_email" id="em">E-mail Adress</label>

    <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" size="30" type="email" value="" class="error">
  </div>
```

Something wrong in my jQuery - can someon suggest what ?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `$(':input')` selector should be `$('input')` instead.

Because `:input` doesn't match any DOMElements.

Comment: What? `:input` is a [deprecated jQuery selector](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) in this case:

```
$('.login').submit(function() {
    $(':input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
            $(this).closest('.field2').removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            $(this).closest('.field2').removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
        }
    })
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

It because when page submitted, page will postback to server. add [event.preventDefault()](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop postback and add [.submit()](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) to the end of code to resubmit. Look code bellow:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();

   $(':input').each(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
      $(".field2").has($(this)).removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
      }
      if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
      $(".field2").has($(this)).removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
      }
   })

   if ($('input[class="error"]').length == 0) {
      $('.login').submit();
   }
});
```

Comment: Now, login form fails to submit at all.

Comment: Like this :

  $('.login').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('input').each(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('valid')) {
            $(this).closest('.field2').removeClass('bg2').addClass('bg1');
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('error')) {
            $(this).closest('.field2').removeClass('bg1').addClass('bg2');
        }
    })
    $(this).submit();
});

Comment: I think you need some validation. try look revised code. this include your all code.

Comment: I do have validation, but I want to add some styling. I'm using jQuery validation plugin. I'm showing errors above fields.

Comment: I think it better to use click() event and add some styling. so after it fire submit() event. I have modify my code.

Comment: Ok, but it is strange because it is adding bg only on second click .

Comment: Maybe that is because of jQuery validation plugin ?

Comment: Maybe you right. However, the key is:
"if page post backed, all java script event will be avoiding. So you need to stop post back by e.preventDefault()"

Comment: If I knew the reason why it is calling only on second click - it would be much better.